# How to generate a list with ReactiveUI?

Tags: c#, reactiveui

I'm trying to trigger the generation of a random sub-selection of items from a list, triggered when a boolean becomes true.

After a lot of frustration, I eventually got to this code which works, but feels very wrong due to the invocation of the command:

```
public class InterruptionViewModel : ReactiveObject
{
    public IBreakTimer BreakTimer { get; }

    public ReactiveCommand<Unit, Unit> UpdateRecommendations { get; }

    [ObservableAsProperty]
    public bool IsInterrupting { get; private set; }

    public ObservableCollection<RecommendationViewModel> Recommendations { get; } = new();

    public InterruptionViewModel(IBreakTimer breakTimer)
    {
        BreakTimer = breakTimer;

        var recommendations = new List<RecommendationViewModel>();
        recommendations.AddRange(new RecommendationViewModel[]
        {
            new("Go for a short walk", "/Assets/walk.jpg"),
            new("Get some water", "/Assets/water.jpg"),
            new("Get in touch with a friend", "/Assets/friend.jpg"),
            new("Do some stretching", "/Assets/stretch.jpg"),
            new("Do some cleaning", "/Assets/clean.jpg"),
            new("Do a 7 minute workout", "/Assets/workout.jpg"),
            new("Go and stare out a window", "/Assets/window.jpg"),
            new("Tidy your desk area", "/Assets/tidy.jpg"),
            new("Stand up and reach for the ceiling", "/Assets/reach.jpg"),
        });

        this.WhenAnyValue(vm => vm.BreakTimer.CurrentState)
            .Select(state => state == TimerState.OnBreak)
            .ToPropertyEx(this, model => model.IsInterrupting, scheduler: RxApp.MainThreadScheduler);

        // This command doesn't feel like the right thing to do...
        UpdateRecommendations = ReactiveCommand.CreateFromObservable(() =>
        {
            Recommendations.Clear();
            var random = new Random();
            Recommendations.AddRange(recommendations.OrderBy(_ => random.Next()).Take(3));
            return Observable.Return(Unit.Default);
        });
        this.WhenAnyValue(vm => vm.IsInterrupting)
            .Where(b => b)
            .Select(_ => Unit.Default)
            .InvokeCommand(this, x => x.RandomCommand);
    }
}
```

I spent a lot of time trying to generate the list as part of the reactive flow, rather than invoking a command to do this, but I couldn't figure out how to actually get it into a list. This is as far as I got:

```
this.WhenAnyValue(vm => vm.IsInterrupting)
    .Where(b => b)
    .Select(_ => new Random())
    .Select(random => recommendations.OrderBy(_ => random.Next()).Take(3))
    .SomehowUpdateAList((values, list) => list.ClearAndAddRange(values)); // <-- What to do here?
```

I tried making the `ObservableCollection<RecommendationViewModel> Recommendations` into an `ObservableAsProperty`, and using `ToPropertyEx()`, but this broke the binding (I imagine it created a new collection rather than updating the existing one in the background).

Any suggestions would be very welcome. I'm just starting out with ReactiveUI, and am eager to learn the best way to do things, and get in the right mindset, rather than limp along with hacks which just 'work'.

Comment: I think the code you have in ReactiveCommand.CreateFromObservable, could easily be put in a method that you call as part of your this.WhenAnyValue(). ALSO not to complicate things, but the ReactiveUI community has another nuget for processing lists of data and streams of data, take a look at https://github.com/reactivemarbles/DynamicData